# PHP simple html dom: apache crashes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using **Simple HTML Dom**. I'm trying to run the following: (with WAMP)

```
$doc = file_get_html('http://www.scoop.it/t/curate-your-personal-learning-environment?page=3');
$comments = array();
$CommentList = $doc->find('#commentList div[class=commentContainer]');
if (count($CommentList) > 0)
    var_dump($CommentList);
foreach ($CommentList as $comment)
{
    $text = $comment->find('span[class^=author]');
    $comments[] = $this::ctrim($text[0]->innertext);
}
```

If I comment out the foreach loop, it runs fine.
Otherwise, the apache crashes.

One important note: If I comment out the inside of the foreach loop, it still crashes.
I added the var dump to make sure that the array has valid items.

EDIT:

Apache logs:

```
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5568
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 5568: Child process is running
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 5568: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 5568: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 5568: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Jul 10 16:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 5568: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: what does apache say? can you post the errorlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be a memory leak:
since your apache says:

> child process exited with status 255

see here:
[PHP Out of Memory - Crashes Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990216/php-out-of-memory-crashes-apache)

> Due to php5 circular references memory leak, after creating DOM
>   object, you must call $dom->clear() to free memory if call
>   file_get_dom() more then once.

from here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm#memory_leak

Comment: Yep! I forgot I had a loop calling the pages, and when I called file_get_html I didn't free that memory. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
$this::ctrim($text[0]->innertext);
```

to

```
self::ctrim($text[0]->innertext);
```

or

```
$this->ctrim($text[0]->innertext);
```

`$obj->method` is an instance call.
`Class::method` is an static call.
`$this::method` does probably something weird...

Comment: The problem is in the foreach loop, I commented everything inside the loop, leaving only the iteration, but it still causes it to crash.