# PHP Out of Memory on ISSET()

Tags: php, performance, out-of-memory

I have this line of code that seems to be giving me the Out of Memory error on PHP.

```
 //Gives OOM when $list[0] is undeclared
 if(isset($list[0]) == false) { $message = 'Variable is not set. Unable to validate variable'; }
```

May I know if there's a way to check if a variable is undeclared and why is isset giving me an Out of Memory error?

Comment: `if(!isset($list[0]))` will work.

Comment: Better use ``!isset($list[0])`` instead of ``isset($list[0]) == false``.

Comment: What is the error saying actually?

Comment: If it's about not enough memory, you need to check your code. Do you get your $list variable from another include or smt?

Comment: What is the [memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)? You can run `echo ini_get('memory_limit');` to find out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Out of Memory - Crashes Apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990216/php-out-of-memory-crashes-apache)

Comment: The number of line that is indicated in the error message doesn't say that it is the line that causes the problem. It is just a line where the memory limit was met.  This line could be in a loop that increments memory usage with each iteration.

Comment: @b0s3 may i know whats the difference between them two? (!isset($list[0])) vs (isset($list[0]) == false)

Comment: It seem to go into an endless loop leading to OOM

Comment: It doesn't work though, I tried changing to (!isset($list[0])

Comment: @toffee.beanns `isset` return `true` or `false`. So no need to do `isset($a) == false`.